# Redis Commander does not show cached data

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I have implemented Redis to my project. It seems to work as when I use Postman to
GET some information from http client. For the first query it needs ~150 ms and for the further ones
just ~5-7 ms. Now, the problem is that when check Redis Commander, it doesnt show anything there. Like nothing has been created.

I set time to live for 60 minutes but still Redis Commander doesnt show me cache.

EDIT: problem solved. needed to changed version of Redis in pom.xml

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
    redis:
      time-to-live: PT60M
```